# How to create a slug from title and subtitle in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to create a slug. it should be a concatenation of title and subtitle.The following is my code and it's not working, i don't know where i went wrong?

```
public function setTitleAttribute($value)
{
$this->attributes['main_title'] = ucfirst($value);
$this->attributes['sub_title'] = $value;
if (! $this->exists) {
  $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($this->attributes['main_title'].$this->attributes['sub_title']);
}
}
```

I need slug as a combination of main_title+sub_title

Comment: in your first line, modify like this, haven't tested but should work `$this->attributes['main_title'] = ucfirst($value) . " ";`

Comment: @Sid : Still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

```
public function to_slug ($string) {

$table = array(
    'Š'=>'S', 'ı'=>'i', 'ğ'=>'g', 'ü'=>'u', 'ş'=>'s', 'ö'=>'o', 'ç'=>'c', 'Ğ'=>'G', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ş'=>'S', 
    'İ'=>'I', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ç'=>'C',
    'š'=>'s', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ć'=>'c',
    'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
    'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
    'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
    'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
    'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
    'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
    'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŕ'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r',
);


 return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-',  strtr($string, $table) );
}
```

I'm using this code and its working for me.
It is also good for utf-8.

Comment: You should try the //TRANSLIT mode of iconv(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use a laravel package:

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Or I use JavaScript when I sent the form:

https://github.com/madflow/jquery-slugify

Comment: eloquent-sluggable is a great and easy to use package. I use it on every project I need slugs for

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated the exact condition like yours passing static data and its working perfectly in my machine.. try below solution.. do some `dd` and see whats the combination of the `main_title` and `sub_title` is resulting. Also check by removing that if condition once.

```
$this->attributes['main_title'] = ucfirst($value) . " ";
$this->attributes['sub_title'] = $value;
$slugToUse = $this->attributes['main_title'] . $this->attributes['sub_title'];
if (! $this->exists) {
  $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($slugToUse);
  }
}
```

Comment: $factory->define(App\features::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
      'main_title' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(3,6)),
      'sub_title' => $faker->sentence(mt_rand(1, 3)),
      'content' => join("\n\n", $faker->paragraphs(mt_rand(3, 6))),
      'header_image_filename'=>$faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = NULL),
      'author_id' => $faker->randomDigitNotNull(),
      'published_at' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 month', '+3 days'),
      'star_profile_id' => $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = NULL),

    ];
});
This is my factory faker,

Comment: when i try to do db:seed, mongo returing an error !!

Comment: production.ERROR: exception 'MongoDuplicateKeyException' with message 'localhost:27017: E11000 duplicate key error index: 70mm.features.$slug_1 dup key: { : null }' in C:\xampp\htdocs\70mm.co\vendor\jenssegers\mongodb\src\Jenssegers\Mongodb\Collection.php:42
Stack trace: - This is showing in laravel.log